# Provide windows avilable cores

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I use the following in my script to find how many available cores I can use.

This is for **Linux**:

```
NPROCS = $(shell grep -c 'processor' /proc/cpuinfo)
```

This is for **Mac** (darwin):

```
NPROCS = $(shell sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
```

How should it be in **Windows**?

Comment: Ugh! On a Mac use `NPROCS=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)`

Comment: `echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - thanks, why this is better ? `NPROCS=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)`

Comment: It's better because a) it gives you exactly what you asked for, b) it is more succinct, c) it requires one less process and d) it has one less dependency.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - thanks, how can I use the `echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` into variable ? like `nprocs`

Comment: Only 2 people in the history of the world know how many quotes, carets, exclamation marks and percent signs you need in anything on Windows and 3 of them are dead. Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of those commands:

```
c:wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List
NumberOfCores=6
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=12

NumberOfCores=6
NumberOfLogicalProcessors=12
```

(here you have two physical processors)

Or as suggested in comments:

```
c:echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
24
```

In Makefile the record should be something like:

```
NPROCS = $(shell echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%)
```

P.S. And the commands you write in question are wrong! You must remove space around `=`

Comment: The spaces around `=` would be wrong in `bash` but OP is actually using the commands within a `Makefile` (that's why they start with `shell`) and spaces are ok in Makefiles.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, @MarkSetchell

Comment: Thanks, how should I get it into variable , as in my question with `NPROCS` ? Im using `Makefile`